# Directory mirror and conditional renaming

Tags: cmd, robocopy

I have a directory of active text files which are used by machines on a manufacturing floor. These files are revision controlled by using an appended tag (eg. 000000**_R1**.pim). These machines can only receive a file with a 6 digit string name (000000.pim). Normally we handle this by using a simple FTP program and renaming them individually during transfer (FTP is the only option with these old machines, unfortunately).

I would like to create a mirror directory that holds the files already renamed, so that I don't have to rename every time programs are pushed to the machine's hard drive. This allows me to provide hard evidence of revision control for the customers.

I have no IT privileges, and no ability to even install software on my computer.

I've written a batch file to do this for me, but it takes about a minute to complete, which is rather tedious. The script tends to delete, copy, and rename around 500 files every time it's run (out of 2,700 files).

```
@echo off 
echo **************************************************** 
echo Please wait while the Manufacturing Directory is updated 
echo **************************************************** 
Set TransTXT="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\pim_Transfer.txt"
Set LogTXT="%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Transfer_Log.txt"
set REMOTEHD="M:\DMS_8055"
set FILELOCA="T:\Fagor\PRG"
REM *** MOVE ALL FILES TO MANUFACTURING NETWORK
robocopy %FILELOCA% %REMOTEHD% /LOG:%LOGTXT% /V /NP /NS /NDL /NJH /NJS /PURGE
echo ****************************************************
echo Copy Complete
echo ****************************************************
REM RENAME ALL FILES
echo Exchanged %DATE% %TIME% > %transtxt%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo ****************************************************
ECHO RENAMING FILES TO MATCH MACHINE REQUIREMENTS:
echo ****************************************************
cd /d "%REMOTEHD%"
for %%x in ("%REMOTEHD%\*.pim") do (
    set curn=%%~nx
    set redn=!curn:~0,6!
    IF /I !curn! neq !redn! (
        echo "!curn!" >> %transtxt%
        IF EXIST "!redn!.pim" (
            echo "!curn! REPLACED !redn!" >> %transtxt%
            del "!redn!.pim"
            ren "%%x" "!curn:~0,6!.pim"
        ) ELSE (
            ren "%%x" "!curn:~0,6!.pim"
        )
    ) 
)
REM *** copy program to a temporary folder
echo ****************************************************
echo Rename Complete
echo ****************************************************
REM start notepad %LogTXT%
REM start notepad %transtxt%
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to handle this - possibly something that doesn't require so many read/writes each time it's ran - but it also needs to be robust enough that it doesn't miss any changes to the source directory. There is a chance that very old files could be moved into my source directory due to customer demands, so using the timestamps won't necessarily work.

Comment: Is there a certain issue with your code? if yes, please elaborate. Does it work as expected and you just want to have it improved and rewritten, then this question is too broad and therefore off-topic here. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve]! Anyway, what about using the [Archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit) attribute?

Comment: Are there multiple revisions being processed? 000000_R1.pim, 000000_R2.pim, 000000_R3.pim,... 000000_R27.pim that would all replace 000000.pim?

Comment: @aschipfl I apologize. I thought this would be a good location, but you are right. My question is definitely too broad. My code works as intended, but I'm trying to find a better way if possible.
The Archive could help reduce the number of writes, but then I'd need to get rid of /purge on robocopy and figure out another way to remove files that were removed from the source folder.

Comment: @lit There shouldn't be multiple revisions, but there could be if we aren't following our procedure correctly.